# COBOL search function

Tags: cobol, mainframe

I'm trying to search a table, but it keeps abending. I'm very new to COBOL and I'm not sure if I'm just making a simple mistake. When I try to debug, it looks as if the parish codes match, so I'm not sure why it's not outputting the territory code. The instructions and my code for this routine are below in case it helps. I know I'm missing alot (like the counts) but I'm just trying to get some output first. Any help would be appreciated!

1. Read each record. If record type is 94, use SEARCH verb to locate parish code in parish/territory table and find territory code. Add territory code to the output record and write the record to disk.
2. If the parish is found in the parish/territory table, increment the count for that territory in the territory table.
3. If the parish is not in the parish/territory table, then abend the program.
4. Print each territory and the corresponding number of policies in that territory to the report.
5. Print counts of total records processed and total policies processed to the report.

```
FILE SECTION.                                               

   FD  REPORT-FILE                                             
       LABEL RECORDS ARE OMITTED                               
       DATA RECORD IS REPORT-RECORD.                           

   01  REPORT-RECORD                  PIC X(132).              

   FD  PRINT-FILE                                              
       LABEL RECORDS ARE OMITTED                               
       DATA RECORD IS PRINT-RECORD.                            

   01  PRINT-RECORD                    PIC X(132).             

   FD  INPUT-FILE                                              
       LABEL RECORD IS STANDARD.                               

       COPY TRNREC94.                                             

       EJECT                                                      

   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                                       

01   record-ws.
    05 rec-record-type  pic x(2)    read input-file 
    05 rec-policy-number    pic x(8)
    05 filler       pic x(5)
    05 rec-parish-code  pic x(3)
    05 filler       pic x(1)
    05 rec-territory-code   pic x(1)
    05 filler       pic x(60)



 01  HEADER.                                                    
       05 FILLER                   PIC X(8)  VALUE 'TSTHC020'.    
       05 FILLER                   PIC X(30) VALUE SPACES.        
       05 FILLER                   PIC X(41)                      
          VALUE 'LOUISIANA FARM BUREAU INSURANCE COMPANIES'.      
       05 FILLER                   PIC X(30) VALUE SPACES.        
       05 FILLER                   PIC X(5)  VALUE 'PAGE '.       
       05 PRINT-PAGE-NUMBER        PIC ZZZZZZ9.                   

   01  HEADER-LINE-2.                                             
       05 FILLER                   PIC X(10) VALUE '10/22/2013'.  



    01  DETAIL-LINE.                                               
        05 DET-TERRITORY            PIC X(2).                      
        05 DET-NUMBER-POLICIES      PIC X(2).                      

    01  COLUMN-LINE.                                               
        05 FILLER                   PIC X(9)  VALUE 'TERRITORY'.   
        05 FILLER                   PIC X(10) VALUE SPACES.        
        05 FILLER                   PIC X(18)                      
           VALUE 'NUMBER OF POLICIES'.                             

    01  TOTAL-LINE.                                                
        05 FILLER                   PIC X(26)                      
           VALUE 'TOTAL RECORDS PROCESSED IS'.                     
        05 TOTAL-RECORDS            PIC X(3).                      
        05 FILER                    PIC X(32)                      
           VALUE 'AND TOTAL POLICIES PROCESSED IS'.    
        05 TOTAL-POLICIES           PIC X(3).                       


    01  PROG-ID.                                                    
        05  FILLER                  PIC X(50)                       
            VALUE 'PROGRAM - TSTXX002- WORKING STORAGE STARTS HERE'.

    01  MISC-VARIABLES-SW.                                          
        05  END-OF-FILE-SW          PIC XXX.                        
            88  ALL-RECORDS-ARE-PROCESSED       VALUE 'YES'.        
            88  MORE-RECORDS                    VALUE 'NO'.         


    01  FILE-STATUS-VALUES.                                         
        05  FILE-STATUS             PIC 99.                         
            88  SUCCESSFUL-READ                 VALUE 0.            
            88  SUCCESSFUL-START                VALUE 0.            
            88  SUCCESSFUL-WRITE                VALUE 0.  
            88  SUCCESSFUL-DELETE               VALUE 0.         
            88  SUCCESSFUL-OPEN                 VALUE 0.         
            88  SUCCESSFUL-CLOSE                VALUE 0.         
            88  END-OF-FILE                     VALUE 10.        
            88  RECORD-NOT-FOUND                VALUE 23.        

        05  PAGE-CONTROLLERS.                                    
            10  A-LINE-COUNT        PIC 999  COMP-3 VALUE 0.     
            10  A-PAGE-COUNT        PIC 999  COMP-3 VALUE 0.     
            10  A-DISK-COUNTER      PIC 9(5) COMP-3 VALUE 0.     

    01  TABLES.                                                  

        05  T1-TERRITORY-VALUES.                                 
            10  FILLER              PIC X(4)  VALUE '0101'.      
            10  FILLER              PIC X(4)  VALUE '0207'.      
            10  FILLER              PIC X(4)  VALUE '0307'.      
            10  FILLER              PIC X(4)  VALUE '0409'.     
            10  FILLER              PIC X(4)  VALUE '0509'.     
            10  FILLER              PIC X(4)  VALUE '0609'.     
            10  FILLER              PIC X(4)  VALUE '0709'.     
            10  FILLER              PIC X(4)  VALUE '0801'.     
            10  FILLER              PIC X(4)  VALUE '0901'.     
            10  FILLER              PIC X(4)  VALUE '1001'.     
            10  FILLER              PIC X(4)  VALUE '1104'.     
            10  FILLER              PIC X(4)  VALUE '1204'.     
            10  FILLER              PIC X(4)  VALUE '1305'.     
            10  FILLER              PIC X(4)  VALUE '1405'.     
            10  FILLER              PIC X(4)  VALUE '1506'.     
            10  FILLER              PIC X(4)  VALUE '1606'.     
            10  FILLER              PIC X(4)  VALUE '1707'.     
            10  FILLER              PIC X(4)  VALUE '1802'.     
            10  FILLER              PIC X(4)  VALUE '1902'.     
            10  FILLER              PIC X(4)  VALUE '2002'.     
            10  FILLER              PIC X(4)  VALUE '2103'.     
            10  FILLER              PIC X(4)  VALUE '2208'.   
            10  FILLER              PIC X(4)  VALUE '2308'.      
            10  FILLER              PIC X(4)  VALUE '2409'.      
            10  FILLER              PIC X(4)  VALUE '2506'.      
            10  FILLER              PIC X(4)  VALUE '2605'.      
            10  FILLER              PIC X(4)  VALUE '2704'.      
            10  FILLER              PIC X(4)  VALUE '2804'.      
            10  FILLER              PIC X(4)  VALUE '2903'.      
            10  FILLER              PIC X(4)  VALUE '3003'.      

         05  T1-TERRITORY-TABLE REDEFINES T1-TERRITORY-VALUES.    
             10  T1-ENTRY                 OCCURS 30 TIMES         
                                            INDEXED BY T1-INDEX.  

                 15 T1-PARISH             PIC XXX.                
                 15 T1-TERRITORY          PIC X.    


 05  T2-TERRITORY-COUNT.                                    
     10  FILLER                   PIC X(4) VALUE '1   '.    
     10  FILLER                   PIC X(4) VALUE '2   '.    
     10  FILLER                   PIC X(4) VALUE '3   '.    
     10  FILLER                   PIC X(4) VALUE '4   '.    
     10  FILLER                   PIC X(4) VALUE '5   '.    
     10  FILLER                   PIC X(4) VALUE '6   '.    
     10  FILLER                   PIC X(4) VALUE '7   '.    
     10  FILLER                   PIC X(4) VALUE '8   '.    
     10  FILLER                   PIC X(4) VALUE '9   '.    

 05  T2-TERRITORY-TABLE REDEFINES T2-TERRITORY-COUNT.       
     10  T2-ENTRY                 OCCURS 9 TIMES            
                                    INDEXED BY T2-INDEX.    
         15 T2-TERRITORY-CODE       PIC X.                  
         15 T2-TERRITORY-COUNTER    PIC XXX.  

PROCEDURE DIVISION.
A000-MAINLINE.                                                   

            PERFORM B000-OPENING-PROCEDURE.                              
            PERFORM B110-PRINT-HEADINGS.                                 
            PERFORM B300-READ-FILE.                               
            PERFORM B500-MAIN-PROCEDURE                                  
                UNTIL END-OF-FILE-SW = 'YES'.                           
            PERFORM B100-CLOSING-PROCEDURE.                              
            STOP RUN.                                                    

        B000-OPENING-PROCEDURE.                                          
              OPEN OUTPUT REPORT-FILE.                                   
              OPEN OUTPUT PRINT-FILE.                                    
              OPEN I-O INPUT-FILE.                                       

        B100-CLOSING-PROCEDURE.                                          
              PERFORM B800-PRINT-TOTAL-LINE.                             
              CLOSE REPORT-FILE.                                         
              CLOSE PRINT-FILE.                                          
              CLOSE INPUT-FILE.                                          

        B200-PRINT-HEADER.                                               
              MOVE HEADER TO PRINT-RECORD.                               
              WRITE PRINT-RECORD.                                        
              MOVE HEADER-LINE-2 TO PRINT-RECORD.                        
              WRITE PRINT-RECORD BEFORE ADVANCING 1.                     

        B300-READ-FILE.                                           
              READ INPUT-FILE NEXT RECORD                                
                   AT END MOVE 'YES' TO END-OF-FILE-SW.                  


        B500-MAIN-PROCEDURE.                                             
             PERFORM B600-SEARCH-TERRITORY                 
             PERFORM B300-READ-FILE.                             


         B600-SEARCH-TERRITORY.                                          
              SET T1-INDEX TO 1.                                         
              SEARCH T1-ENTRY                                            
                   AT END                                                
                        DISPLAY 'PARISH NOT FOUND IN TABLE'              
                        CALL 'CEE3ABD' USING BY VALUE 12 BY VALUE 1      
                   WHEN                                                  
                        REC-94-PARISH-CODE = T1-PARISH(T1-INDEX)         
                        MOVE T1-TERRITORY(T1-INDEX) TO   
                               DET-TERRITORY.                            


         B700-PRINT-DETAIL-LINE.                                         
               MOVE DETAIL-LINE TO PRINT-RECORD.                         
               WRITE PRINT-RECORD BEFORE ADVANCING 1.                    

         B800-PRINT-TOTAL-LINE.                                          
               MOVE A-LINE-COUNT TO TOTAL-RECORDS.                       
               MOVE TOTAL-LINE TO PRINT-RECORD.                          
               WRITE PRINT-RECORD AFTER ADVANCING 1.                     

         B900-PRINT-COLUMN-LINE.                                         
               MOVE COLUMN-LINE TO PRINT-RECORD.                         
               WRITE PRINT-RECORD BEFORE ADVANCING 1.  

         B110-PRINT-HEADINGS.                                            
               ADD 1 TO A-PAGE-COUNT.                                    
               MOVE A-PAGE-COUNT TO PRINT-PAGE-NUMBER.                   
               PERFORM B200-PRINT-HEADER.                                
               PERFORM B900-PRINT-COLUMN-LINE.
```

Comment: What is the definition of REC-94-PARISH-CODE from your copybook? You also don't have anything to check for type 94. If you have other record types, do they have the parish code at the same position? If not, and there is another record type physically before the 94 record, you won't get a match (unless you are unlucky) and you'll get your abend.

Comment: COPYBOOK: TRNREC94 
01 RECORD-TYPE-94.                           
    05 REC-94-TYPE                  PIC X(2). 
    05 REC-94-POLICY-NUMBER         PIC X(8). 
    05 FILLER                       PIC X(5). 
    05 REC-94-PARISH-CODE           PIC X(3). 
    05 FILLER                       PIC X(1). 
    05 REC-94-TERRITORY-CODE        PIC X(1). 
    05 FILLER                       PIC X(60).

The other record types don't have parish code at the same position I think. I'm not sure how the copybook works, which is why I didn't check for type 94 bc I thought copying record 94 would be enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It think your problem is in not testing for the 94s. It is not enough to just include that one copybook.

```
    B500-MAIN-PROCEDURE.                         
         IF REC-94-TYPE EQUAL TO "94"                    
             PERFORM B600-SEARCH-TERRITORY
         END-IF                 
         PERFORM B300-READ-FILE
         .
```

Ideally you would have an 88 for the record-types, which you may find on another copybook for the same file.

Note that I have used a scope-delimiter (the END-IF) and limited the number of periods/full-stops to the mandatory one before a paragraph/SECTION starts or the end of the program is reached.

You are doing IO, you even have 88s set up, but you aren't doing any status checking on the IO. You should. Always.

Why have you opened your input for I-O? If you have an ordinary sequential file, read it, and write a new one. Otherwise you must create a back-up before your program runs. If you don't, your update-in-place becomes a corrupt-in-place.

Comment: I used the IF statement, and as I'm debugging I see that I'm finally reading the correct records. I'm only getting one line of output that is just showing me total records read though. I need to figure out how to increment the count for each territory once the parish codes are found (a-disk-counter is simply counting the records I'm reading which also took me long enough to figure out), bc I don't think my MOVE statement is working how I thought it would. Any tips on how to increment the count in the territory-count table? Thanks for your patience as I'm obviously extremely new to this!

Comment: @MeaganOh B500-MAIN-PROCEDURE isn't writing anything - that is where you might add a counter and an output statement? At any rate, its time you started thinking for yourself again. Bill answerd your question and you should acknowledge that by accepting this answer and maybe ticking the upvote button.